# "@" symbol added to ranges inside supported functions (=SUM(A*B))

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

The xlsx file i'm making needs to be able to calculate sums for it's generated tables, which are printed as cells due to limitations in table styling.
This means I have two columns that i want to multiply across a row, and sum down a column, like so:
[intended table style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWgbq.png)

my issue is that as i try to make that table, the formula has '@' symbols added to the formula, like so:`=SUM(@A2:A10*@B2:B10)`.

This doesn't occur if you just sum a single reigon (i.e. =SUM(A2:A10)) only when two ranges are getting multiplied. adding _xlfn. to the sum in the script has no impact. Here's the script used to make the excel file in the image:

```
# Sumfail example
import openpyxl

wb= openpyxl.Workbook()

for row in range(1,10):
    wb.active[f'A{row}']=row
    wb.active[f'B{row}']=row

wb.active['B10']='=SUM(A1:A9*B1:B9)'
wb.save('killMeNow.xlsx')
```

Does anyone know why this happens, and how to avoid it? I have a simple solution of find/replacing the @ symbol, but long term that isn't really sustainable.

Edit: found out why - it's treating it as an array formula, despite it having a single cell output. Probably because of that array1*array2 part. Still don't know how to solve this, though.

Comment: `A1:A9*B1:B9` *is* an array formula, and it's a [relatively new addition](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) to Excel to be able to enter them in this way. Perhaps they're not yet fully supported by OpenPyxl. Could you use `sumproduct` instead?

Comment: https://media.vlipsy.com/vlips/zmhmlR6M/preview.jpg

TLDC: Yes

Comment: they shall write legends of your glory stuart, many thanks

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61138029/9758194). There are a bunch of related questions in the side of that page that could help you in particular. For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66008301/9758194) one.