# excel file open error after input formula with python

Tags: python, excel

I wrote FILTER formula in excel file by python.
But there is formula error when I open that excel file.
Code as following,

`wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')`
`ws = wb['Sheet1']`
`ws['A2'].value = '=FILTER(A1:H13,H1:H13="N")'`
`wb.save('test_m.xlsx')`

There is no error when running python but there is error(formula) when I open saved 'test_m.xlsx' file.
But when I get value by print(ws['A2'].value) and input excel file, it works.

Does anybody know the possible reason?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66010728

Comment: Also see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66008301/symbol-appearing-after-inserting-if-formula-into-excel-using-openpyxl#comment116712216_66010728) by the developer of openpyxl.

Comment: Thank you, @BigBen. It really gave me the hope. But I tried `ws.formula_attributes['A2'] = {'t': 'array', 'ref': "A2:L20"}` and it doesn't work as well :( .There is still error when I open saved files and ask to remove the formula..

Comment: You may have more luck with [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_dynamic_arrays.html).

Comment: Yes. it seems xlsxwriter can do this.. Anyway as you know, xlsxwriter can't open an existing file.. I already finished most of code work with openpyxl, several hundreds of code lines, so I really don't want to re-write the whole code with xlsxwriter from the beginning.. Is there any other possible way?

Comment: You might try the results of [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=dynamic+array+formula+openpyxl). I don't know how much support openpyxl (at least the current version) has for dynamic array formulas. `xlwings` can open an existing file, and should in theory work with dynamic array formulas, though it requires an installation of Excel.

Comment: It took 7 days for me to re-write code with xlsxwriter. Now everything is OK and I'd like to say I love xlsxwriter~!! It runs faster than openpyxl and documentation is more friendly than others. The only cons is it doesn't support read/modify, then I used excel formula to solve.