# OpenPyxl, loop a formula across columns using .format()?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I use openpyxl to create Excel files from Python. I want to take a pandas Dataframe, insert it into a spreadsheet and then summarize column A, B and C with a for loop. (formula in cell A5, B5 and C6 ). However, I'm struggle with how to change the formula string in the loop so I summarize the correct column.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

data

wb1 = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws1 = wb1.active

rows = dataframe_to_rows(data, index=False, header=False)
for r_idx, row in enumerate(rows, 2):
    for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
        ws1.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx, value=value)

for col in ws1.iter_cols(min_row=5, max_row=5, min_col=1, max_col=3):
    for cell in col:
        cell.value = '=SUMMA(A2:A4)' # can I use .format() here in a smart way so A2:A4 changes to # B2:B4 and so on?         
        
wb1.save('test.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
for col in ws1.iter_cols(min_row=5, max_row=5, min_col=1, max_col=3):
    for cell in col:
        cell.value = '=SUMMA({0}2:{0}4)'.format(cell.column)
```

Comment: Nice! However, It throws back an error. Maybe becauses my col iterator is not returning a single number, instead  col prints (<Cell 'Sheet'.A5>,), (<Cell 'Sheet'.B5>,) (<Cell 'Sheet'.C5>,)'

Comment: That is probably it. I'll update my answer slightly.

Comment: You can do this without your own fragile counter and converter: cells with tell you their column_letter

Comment: Why am I getting a "@" after the = ??

Comment: Michelangelo check out this question [openpyxl: '@' is inserted to formula when saving to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61705150/openpyxl-is-inserted-to-formula-when-saving-to-file)

Answer (score 1):

The most recent edit above did not work for me. Using
`cell.value = '=SUMMA({0}2:{0}4)'.format(cell.column)` results in the formula being output with numbers in the place of column letters (ie, =SUMMA(12:14)). This is fixed with `cell.value = '=SUMMA({0}2:{0}4)'.format(cell.column_letter)`