# openpyxl inserts @ in excel formulas

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to save excel sheet with below formula but it always creates @ prefix.

```
check = workbookActive[excelColumns[len(args.input_files)+1]+str(i)] 
             
                        check.value = '=_xlfn.IF(_xlfn.AND(C{}:{}{}=B{}),{},{})'.format(i,excelColumns[len(args.input_files)],i,i,'"Match"','"MisMatch"')
```

This is what I am getting in excel sheet:

=IF(AND(@C11:D11=B11),"Match","MisMatch")

I tried using _xlfn but seems to not solve the issue

Comment: Something that Excel is doing after you open the workbook, nothing to do with Openpyxl. Probably a later version of Excel and C11:D11 being a 'implicit intersection'.

Comment: @Srinivas B, does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61705150/openpyxl-is-inserted-to-formula-when-saving-to-file